# Python, undetected chromedriver

Tags: python, undetected-chromedriver

i got a code for load cookies to binance.com (i dump them before and save in cookies.pkl)
So i try to load it to the site, but it didn't login me and back to register page. How to solve it ?

`here is my code:

```
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb")) - For dump cookies
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
 
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get('https://www.binance.com/ru/my/wallet/account/main/withdrawal/crypto/BTS')
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(9)`
```

as you can see i tried to use the get method of the driver instead of refresh. But I was again back to the registration page